# bibtex doesn't show complete reference

Tags: bibtex, apa6

I am writing Journalist with `\usepackage{apa6}` and `apacite` for `bibtex`. Well the problem is that the last cite doesn't show completely.

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{7.5cm}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\abstract{
\section{Abstract}
\blindtext


\par\medskip
{\textit{Keywords:} Lorem, ipsum, dolor.}


\section{Resumen}
\blindtext
\par\medskip
{\textit{Palabras clave:} Lorem, ipsum, dolor.}
}


\begin{document}

\title{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\author{ultrices tellus hendrerit}
\affiliation{\texttt{Loremipsum@hotmail.com}\\Beer University}
\shorttitle{Lorem ipsum}
\maketitle

\epigraph{``No todo lo que importa puede medirse fácilmente.\\
No todo lo que puede medirse importa realmente…''}{Albert Einstein}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Resumen}


\section*{Introducción}

\nocite{Cajiao}
\nocite{Ausubel}
\nocite{Albornoz}
\nocite{Hamburger}
\nocite{Toranzos}
\nocite{Orden}

\blindtext

\section*{Marco Teórico}

\Blindtext

\bibliography{referencias}

\end{document}
```

referebcias.bib

```
@book{Cajiao,
    author    = "Francisco Cajiao",
    title     = "Evaluar es valorar: Dialogo sobre la evaluación del aprendizaje en el aula para comprender el decreto 1290 de 2009",
    publisher = "Editorial magisterio",
    year      = "2010",
    address   = "Bogotá",
}, 

@book{Ausubel,
    author    = "David Ausubel",
    title     = "Psicología Educativa",
    publisher = "Editorial Trillas",
    year      = "2005",
    address   = "México",
}, 

@book{Albornoz,
    author    = "Luis Baudilio Albornoz",
    title     = "La evaluación decretada",
    publisher = "Editorial SEM",
    year      = "2008",
    address   = "Bogotá",
}, 

@book{Hamburger,
    author    = "Alvaro Andres Hamburger",
    title     = "Escribir para objetivar el saber",
    publisher = "Ediciones Unisalle",
    year      = "2010",
    address   = "Bogotá",
},

@magazine{Toranzos,
    author  = "Lilia Toranzos",
    title   = "Evaluación y calidad",
    journal = "Revista Iberoamericana de Educación",
    year    = "1996",
    number  = "10",
    pages   = "63-78",
},

@magazine{Orden,
    author  = "de la Orden, A. and Asensio, I. and Carballo, R. and Fernández Díaz, J. and Fuentes, A. and García Ramos, J.M. and Guardia, S.",
    title   = "Desarrollo y validación de un modelo de calidad universitaria como base para su evaluación",
    journal = "RELIEVE",
    year    = "1997",
    volume  = "3",
    number  = "1",
},
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue (see [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnb12.png)). Voting to close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain where your last line disappeared. To solve it to a desired output, I added one blank line at the end of your document on purpose. I run these lines:

> pdflatex mal-apa6.tex
>   bibtex mal-apa6.aux
>   pdflatex mal-apa6.tex

```
%! pdflatex mal-apa6.tex
%! bibtex mal-apa6.aux
%! pdflatex mal-apa6.tex
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{7.5cm}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\abstract{%
\section{Abstract}
\blindtext\par\medskip
{\textit{Keywords:} Lorem, ipsum, dolor.}
\section{Resumen}
\blindtext\par\medskip
{\textit{Palabras clave:} Lorem, ipsum, dolor.}
}% End of \abstract...

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{referencias.bib}
@book{Cajiao,
  author =       "Francisco Cajiao",
  title =        "Evaluar es valorar: Dialogo sobre la evaluación del aprendizaje en el aula para comprender el decreto 1290 de 2009",
    publisher = "Editorial magisterio",
    year = "2010",
    address = "Bogotá",
    }
@book{Ausubel,
  author =       "David Ausubel",
  title =        "Psicología Educativa",
    publisher = "Editorial Trillas",
    year = "2005",
    address = "México",
    }
@book{Albornoz,
  author =       "Luis Baudilio Albornoz",
  title =        "La evaluación decretada",
    publisher = "Editorial SEM",
    year = "2008",
    address = "Bogotá",
    },
@book{Hamburger,
  author =       "Alvaro Andres Hamburger",
  title =        "Escribir para objetivar el saber",
    publisher = "Ediciones Unisalle",
    year = "2010",
    address = "Bogotá",
    }
@magazine{Toranzos,
    author = "Lilia Toranzos",
    title = "Evaluación y calidad",
    journal = "Revista Iberoamericana de Educación",
    year = "1996",
    number = "10",
    pages = "63-78",    
    }
@magazine{Orden,
    author = "de la Orden, A. and Asensio, I. and Carballo, R. and Fernández Díaz, J. and Fuentes, A. and García Ramos, J.M. and Guardia, S.",
    title = "Desarrollo y validación de un modelo de calidad universitaria como base para su evaluación",
    journal = "RELIEVE",
    year = "1997",
    volume = "3",
    number = "1",
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\title{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\author{ultrices tellus hendrerit}
\affiliation{\texttt{Loremipsum@hotmail.com}\\Beer University}
\shorttitle{Lorem ipsum}
\maketitle
\epigraph{``No todo lo que importa puede medirse fácilmente \\
No todo lo que puede medirse importa realmente…''}{Albert Einstein}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Resumen}
\section*{Introducción}
\nocite{Cajiao}
\nocite{Ausubel}
\nocite{Albornoz}
\nocite{Hamburger}
\nocite{Toranzos}
\nocite{Orden}
\blindtext
\section*{Marco Teórico}
\Blindtext
\bibliography{referencias}
an empty line
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Thanks, is a inussually error and the solution is equally